# Error in matrix index dimension for colored noise

Tags: matlab, matrix

The objective of the following code is to generate a colored gaussian signal from a random gaussian noise;perform Fast Fourier Transform and also generate power signal. Questions:

1. I wanted to generate gaussian colored noise such that the power spectral densities is proprtional to 1/f^beta where beta=1,-1,2,0. Is the process correct?
2. The code generates error

   ??? Error using ==> rdivide
   Matrix dimensions must agree.

   Error in ==> expl at 9
   x = x .* 1./(f.^2);
   Kindly help in solving this.Thank you

Answer (score 0):

`f` has 1025 elements, and `x` has 2001 elements. But their length needs to be equal. You should change one of them.

Answer (score 0):

I executed your code, then looked at the size of what you generated.

```
>> whos f x
  Name      Size              Bytes  Class     Attributes

  f         1x1025             8200  double              
  x         1x2001            16008  double
```

For the line in question to execute, you don't think that having f and x the same sizes would be useful?

When MATLAB says that matrix dimensions don't agree, it would seem the first place to look would be the dimensions of the variables in question. :)

Comment: Yes,i checked using the size command.So,how do I make them equal?Please help;i am a novice in matlab.

Comment: @sts You should first re-read your code, then understand why `numel(0:1/Fs:2)` and `numel(linspace(0,1,NFFT/2+1))` are different. Then you should re-think your problem and decide which of these two to use (or suitably modify depending on what you're doing). Once you do that, `x = x .* 1./(f.^2);` will evaluate without a fuss :)